# how can i select two columns from a table and combine the values into one column

Tags: mysql

i have a table called tbl_products and i want to combine the columns start_date and end_date into one column named dates but have all the values from both columns be displayed on a seperate row. I have looked into concat but all that does is combine both columns together in a cell for each row.

sample data:

```
tbl_products.start_date
------------------------
10/1/2011
10/2/2011
10/3/2011
10/4/2011

tbl_products.end_date
----------------------
11/1/2011
11/2/2011
11/3/2011
11/4/2011
```

then after their combined the result would be

```
tbl_products.dates
-------------------
10/1/2011
10/2/2011
10/3/2011
10/4/2011
11/1/2011
11/2/2011
11/3/2011
11/4/2011
```

i've looked all over online and cant find out how i can do this. any clue how?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
select tbl_products.start_date from tbl_products
union 
select tbl_products.end_date from tbl_products
```

Comment: i tried that as well, but for some reason all i got returned was 3 rows as one column

Comment: check union all in place of union might be problem with duplicate data

Comment: is union selecting distinct dates? because i have alot of duplicate dates. the 3 rows that was returned look like unique dates.

Comment: ps: is it possible to make that into one select statement?

Comment: yes, problem is solved thanks, but is it possible to make it into one select or that is how its done

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT tbl_products.start_date FROM tbl_products  
UNION ALL  
SELECT tbl_products.end_date FROM tbl_products
```